# Laravel 9 migration fails after switching to mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I have a locally developed laravel project with sqlite. For deployment reasons I want to switch to mysql. Unfortunately my relation migrations do not work anymore and produce the following error (I have made sure the order in which they run is correct, all other required tables are generated first and look correct)

```
Can't create table `laraveltest`.`test1s_test2s` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") 
(SQL: alter table `test1s_test2s` add constraint `test1s_test2s_test1_id_foreign` foreign key (`suacap_id`) 
references `test1s` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

The migration looks like this:

test1

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('test1s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
...
```

test2

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('test2s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
...
```

relation table test1s_test2s

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('test1s_test2s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary(['test1_id', 'test2_id']);
        $table->string('test1_id');
        $table->foreign('test1_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('test1s')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('test2_id');
        $table->foreign('test2_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('test2s')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

I'm guessing this is related to the primary keys not being unsigned while the bigInt id's of the other tables are? I tried modifying

```
$table->primary(['test1_id', 'test2_id'])->unsigned();
```

but that does not work.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think whenever u make something Foreign keys they should be UNSIGNED BIGINT not string , in Laravel 9  - $table->foreignId('user_id');
also read the official document [Laravel Official Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId)

Comment: Thank you, changing $table->string('test1_id'); to $table->unsignedBigInt('test1_id'); worked. However I wonder why artisan make migration set them out to be strings in the first place.

Comment: I am not getting your second question properly but when we use Laravel artisan command migration it only have id and timestamp only rest we need to  make in by ourselves . if still u have some question pls let me know